# Simple, manual-start user instructions in case Windows CD fails to autostart

Tags: windows, cd

Our CD autostarts, but occasionally customers have that disabled (by a CD burner, etc.).

As a backup, we include instructions on the back of our CD (below).  I'm trying to find better instructions, for Windows XP and above. (Ideally for Windows 98 and above)

**CURRENT**

If it does not auto-start:
Repeat instructions (above) once. If that fails again:

1. Click **Start** | **My Computer**  or double-click **My Computer** on your Windows® desktop.
2. Double-click CD drive. Looks like:
     OurCompany CD (D:)
3. CD Contents are listed, usually to the right.
4. Double-click **Start**, in the list.

But the My Computer option isn't always on the Desktop and when it is customers have trouble finding it.  And Vista doesn't label the start button

**ALTERNATIVE**

Click "Start" | "Run"
In the box in front of "Open:" type : d:start  (where 'd' is drive letter for your CD-ROM.

Problem here is that some people won't know what their CD ROM drive letter is.

Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

One way might be : make an icon on your CD, and have user look for that icon.

Make the icon stand out so it's easy to look for and just tell them to double-click the icon.

Use the same icon on start.exe too.

And you might as well move everything else into its own folder on the CD, leaving only autorun.inf and start.exe on the CD's root.

Comment: Yep, we already do that. I couldn't show that easily in the question, so I just left it out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the Windows+E key will bring up Windows Explorer. You could ask them to press that key combination, and that will at least get them an Explorer window without having to go to the desktop...

Comment: I've had many occasions to talk someone through using Explorer to find the CD drive.  It's surprisingly hard for them to find things. You and I see c:\  and d:\\(cdrom) etc. But to an average user, they just see a LOT of overwhelming text.